# How to concat all values associated with a key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation, window-functions

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
    user,
    phoneType, --from ['A','B','C','D', 'E'], user can have any number of any type
    uniquePhoneID, --unique string identifying the phone
    day_id --date; record does not necessarily exist for every seen user + phoneType every day, represented as number in example
);

INSERT INTO table1 
VALUES (1, 'A', xyz, 1),
       (1, 'A', abc, 1),
       (1, 'B', def, 2),
       (1, 'A', xyz, 2),
       (1, 'C', hij, 4),
       (1, 'A' xyz, 5),
       (2, 'C', w, 9),
       (2, 'D', z, 10),
       (2, 'A', p, 10),
       (2, 'E', c, 11),
       (3, 'A', r, 19),
       (3, 'B', q, 19),
       (3, 'B', q, 20),
       (3, 'B', f, 20),
       (3, 'B', y, 21);
```

A single user, uniquePhoneID, day_id will only show up at most once, but not necessarily at all on any given day.
I am looking to concatenate each user in the table with their 4 phoneTypes in alphabetical order, so the result is as follows:

```
1 | AABC
2 | ACDE
3 | ABBB
```

I have tried a few different ways of doing this but I am unsure how to get the answer I am looking for.

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description recommends, can you please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version. Also your sample data table definition is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `user` is a reserved word, so you will have to resolve that.  Otherwise, I think something like this will work for you:

```
select user, string_agg (phonetype, '' order by phonetype)
from table1
group by user
```

-- EDIT 4/21/2022 --

Aah, okay.  I did not glean that from the original question.

What if you used the distinct on the original table before the aggregation?

```
select userid, string_agg (phonetype, '' order by phonetype)
from (select distinct userid, phonetype, uniquephoneid from table1) x
group by userid
```

I got these results from this version:

```
1   AABC
2   ACDE
3   ABBB
```

If that logic still doesn't work, can you alter the sample data to find an example where it fails?

Comment: You can delimit reserved words with quotes if there's a problem, eg `select "user" ...`

Comment: This will not give the desired answer since some phoneTypes showing up more than once need to be handled differently. Ie if A shows up with two distinct uniquePhoneIDs then no problem. But A, xyz shows up 3 times. Using a simple string_agg will cause this record to show up 3 times in the aggregate string, when it should be once only for xyz (with another A from abc)

Comment: Also it goes without saying that simply adding distinct to the front won’t solve it either, since A should show up twice. From xyz and abc.